# How to get the value from a list based on highest probability?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list `A = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]`
and a list `B` which gives the probability of list `A` i.e. `B = [0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.15,0.6,0.22,0.4,0.3,0.32]`

I need to choose a value from `A` based on the highest probability of `B`. Here it is obvious that the highest value in `B` is `0.6` so I need to choose the number `6` from list `A`. How an I write the code in python?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!  Here you can ① post your code (as a [mcve]), ② describe what you observe it does (with which input), and ③ describe what you expect to observe instead.  This results in a clear question which can be answered.  Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read the [How-To-Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn more about this.

Comment: How should ties (joint highest values) be handled?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can use numpy:

```
import numpy as np
print(A[np.argmax(B)])
```

`np.argmax` returns the index of the max element. And we can simply use that index to access `A`'s element.

Answer (score 2):

How about this:

```
print(max(zip(B,A))[1])
```

Actually @Dim78 suggested and measured that creating the tuples (`zip()` does that) is more costly than searching twice (once for the maximum and once for its position).  I double-checked that and agree.  The effect also doesn't go away for larger lists or when switching to another Python version.

Of course searching for the found maximum can be costly in case comparison of the values is very costly (for plain numbers it isn't), so in *general* this version is inferior.

But for the special case we have here, double searching actually *is* faster (in all cases I tried out):

```
python3 -c 'import timeit; print(timeit.timeit("a[b.index(max(b))]", setup="import numpy as np; a=list(np.random.rand(1000000)); b=list(np.random.rand(1000000))", number=100))'
4.586365897208452

python3 -c 'import timeit; print(timeit.timeit("max(zip(b,a))[1]", setup="import numpy as np; a=list(np.random.rand(1000000)); b=list(np.random.rand(1000000))", number=100))'
6.770604271441698
```

Comment: It's a unique way to do it. But wouldn't it first iterate over the entire list, to create tuples out of them, and them iterate over the zip again to find max?

Comment: The `zip()` creates an iterator (in Python3; in Python2 consider using `izip()` or switching to Python3) creating tuples, and the `max()` will consume these tuples linearly.  I'd be interested in a version which works without building tuples but I don't think it's possible without searching twice.

Answer (score 1):

```
A = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
B = [0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.15,0.6,0.22,0.4,0.3,0.32]
>>> A[max(enumerate(B), key=lambda x:x[1])[0]]
6
```

As suggested by @bro-grammer, a `zip` version:

```
>>> max(zip(A,B), key=lambda x:x[1])
6
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
maxA=A[B.index(max(B))]
```

Also you could try method argmax from NumPy lib.

Comment: That would search for the max, then search for it _again_ to find its index. That's not optimal.

Comment: See my post's edit:  You are right, searching twice is faster than building the tuples.  I did a non-edit to be able to revoke my downvote :)

Answer (score 0):

An option with a dictionary (maybe you can use this dictionary later):

```
d = dict(zip(A, B)) # {1: 0.1, 2: 0.2, 3: 0.3, 4: 0.4, 5: 0.15, 6: 0.6, 7: 0.22, 8: 0.4, 9: 0.3}
m = max(d, key=lambda x: d[x]) # 6
```